# Sorting algorithms for data of known statistical distribution?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, statistics, complexity-theory

It just occurred to me, if you know something about the distribution (in the statistical sense) of the data to sort, the performance of a sorting algorithm might benefit if you take that information into account.

So my question is, are there any sorting algorithms that take into account that kind of information? How good are they?

An example to clarify: if you know the distribution of your data to be Gaussian, you could estimate mean and average on the fly as you process the data. This would give you an estimate of the final position of each number, which you could use to place them close to their final position.

I'm pretty surprised the answer isn't a wiki link to a thourough page discussing this issue. Isn't this a very common case (the Gaussian case, for example)?

I'm adding a bounty to this question, because I'm looking for definite answers with sources, not speculation. Something like "in the case of gaussian distributed data, XYZ algorithm is the fastest on average, as was proved by Smith et al. [1]". However any additional information is welcome.

Comment: There are several algorithms that take information on the data into account and some are already mentioned in the answers. The real question is what kind of information you have specifically. There is no 'generic' algorithm that takes advantage of any kind of information you have.

Comment: How would you represent your distribution? - alternatively - are you looking for a specific solution for gaussian distribution?

Comment: "I'm looking for definite answers with sources, not speculation." - If a source is not supplied - it doesn't mean it is a speculation. An answer may reflect original ideas and still be correct...

Comment: @static_rtti: I have added to my answer given your new criteria.

Comment: I don't want to add this as an answer but the [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algorithm used in the CPython interpreter is an adaptive hybrid sort that takes into consideration the properties of the data its given. This might be useful to you.

Comment: As long as you know the cdf of the distribution, you can always map the original data to samples from the uniform distribution.

Comment: Great question, this should be a common problem at least for the gaussian case.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the data you are sorting has a known distribution, I would use a **[Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)** algorithm.   You could add some extra logic to it so that you calculated the size and/or positions of the various buckets based upon properties of the distribution (ex: for Gaussian, you might have a bucket every (sigma/k) away from the mean, where sigma is the standard deviation of the distribution).

By having a known distribution and modifying the standard Bucket Sort algorithm in this way, you would probably get the **[Histogram Sort](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/histogramSort.html)** algorithm or something close to it.  Of course, your algorithm would be computationally faster than the the Histogram Sort algorithm because there would probably not be a need to do the first pass (described in the link) since you already know the distribution.

**Edit:** given your new criteria of your question, (though my previous answer concerning Histogram Sort links to the respectable NIST and contains performance information), here is a peer review journal article from the International Conference on Parallel Processing:

[Adaptive Data Partition for Sorting Using Probability Distribution](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~cding/Documents/Publications/icpp04.pdf)

The authors claim this algorithm has better performance (up to 30% better) than the popular Quick-Sort Algorithm.

Comment: Considering Quick-Sort as the reference sorting algorithm is quite skewed. IntroSort improves on it by special-casing the small arrays that occur in the recursion, TimSort (and a few other variations) also improve on it by detecting patterns (ascending / descending blocks) on the fly. Interesting paper still :)

Answer (score 19):

Sounds like you might want to read [Self-Improving Algorithms](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0884): they achieve an eventual optimal expected running time for *arbitrary* input distributions.

> We give such self-improving algorithms
>   for two problems: (i) sorting a
>   sequence of numbers and (ii) computing
>   the Delaunay triangulation of a planar
>   point set. Both algorithms achieve
>   optimal expected limiting complexity.
>   The algorithms begin with a training
>   phase during which they collect
>   information about the input
>   distribution, followed by a stationary
>   regime in which the algorithms settle
>   to their optimized incarnations.

If you already know your input distribution is approximately Gaussian, then perhaps another approach would be more efficient in terms of space complexity, but in terms of expected running time this is a rather wonderful result.

Answer (score 6):

Knowing the data source distribution, one can build a good hash function. Knowing the distribution well, the hash function may prove to be a perfect hash function, or close to perfect for many input vectors.

Such function would divide an input of size n into n bins, such that the smallest item would map into the 1st bin, and the largest item would map to the last bin. When the hash is perfect- we would achieve sort just be inserting all the items into the bins.

Inserting all the items into a hash table, then extracting them by order will be O(n) when the hash is perfect (assuming the hash function calculation cost is O(1), and the underline hash data structure operations are O(1)).

I would use an array of fibonacci heaps to implement the hash-table.

For input vector for which the hash function won't be perfect (but still close to perfect), it would still be much better than O(nlogn). When it is perfect - it would be O(n). I'm not sure how to calculate the average complexity, but if forced to, I would bet on O(nloglogn).

Comment: I'm sorry but your "Note" is completely misinformed. If you know a source of data to be Gaussian, you can compute average complexity, even if the histogram of your (finite) data won't exactly match a Gaussian curve. That's the whole point of statistics: reason on infinite sample size, apply on finite sample size (while taking into account the effect of finiteness if it is not negligeable, of course). Knowing a source of data is gaussian is completely different from knowing the exact values.

Answer (score 6):

Computer sorting algorithms can be classified into
two categories, comparison-based sorting and
non-comparison-based sorting. For comparison-based
sorting, the sorting time in its best-case performance is
Ω (nlogn), while in its worst-case performance the
sorting time can rise up to O(n2 ). In recent years,
some improved algorithms have been proposed to
speed up comparison-based sorting, such as advanced
quick sort according to data distribution characteristics
. However, the average sorting time for these
algorithms is just Ω (nlog2n), and only in the best-case
can it reach O(n).
Different from comparison-based sorting,
non-comparison-based sorting such as count sorting,
bucket sorting and radix sorting depends mainly on key
and address calculation. When the values of keys are
finite ranging from 1 to m, the computational
complexity of non-comparison-based sorting is
O(m+n). Particularly, when m=O(n), the sorting time
can reach O(n). However, when m=n2, n3, …., the
upper bound of linear sorting time can not be obtained.
Among non-comparison-based sorting, bucket sorting
distributes a group of records with similar keys into the
appropriate “bucket”, then another sorting algorithm is
applied to the records in each bucket. With bucket
sorting, the partition of records into m buckets is less
time consuming, while only a few records will be
contained in each bucket so that “cleanup sorting”
algorithm can be applied very fast. Therefore,
bucket sorting has the potential to asymptotically save
sorting time compared with Ω (nlogn) algorithms.
Obviously, how to uniformly distribute all records into
buckets plays a critical role in bucket sorting. Hence what you need is a method to construct a hash function
according to data distribution, which is used to
uniformly distribute n records into n buckets based on
the key of each record. Hence, the sorting time of the
proposed bucket sorting algorithm will reach O(n)
under any circumstance.

check this paper: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5170434&tag=1

Answer (score 5):

Bucket sort would give you a linear time sorting algorithm, as long as you can compute the CDF of each point in O(1) time.

The algorithm, which you can also look up elsewhere, is as follows:

```
a = array(0, n - 1, [])          // create an empty list for each bucket
for x in input:
  a[floor(n * cdf(x))].append(x) // O(1) time for each x
input.clear()
for i in {0,...,n - 1}:
  // this sorting step costs O(|a[i]|^2) time for each bucket
  // but most buckets are small and the cost is O(1) per bucket in expectation
  insertion_sort(a[i])
  input.concatenate(a[i])
```

The running time is O(n) in expectation because in expectation there are O(n) pairs (x, y) such that x and y fall in the same bucket, and the running time of insertion sort is precisely O(n + # pairs in the same bucket). The analysis is similar to that of [FKS static perfect hashing](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring07/erik/L11.pdf).

EDIT: If you don't know the distribution, but you know what family it's from, you can just estimate the distribution in O(n), in the Gaussian case by computing the mean and variance, and then use the same algorithm (incidentally, computing the cdf in this case is nontrivial).

Answer (score 4):

You could use that information in quicksort to select the pivot value. I think it would improve the probability of the algorithm staying away of the O(N**2) worst case complexity.

Answer (score 3):

I think [cycle sort](http://corte.si/posts/code/cyclesort/index.html) falls into this category. You use it when you know the exact position that you want each element to end up at.

> Cyclesort has some nice properties - for certain restricted types of data it can do a stable, in-place sort in linear time, while guaranteeing that each element will be moved at most once.

Comment: You only know an estimate of the final position if you know the distribution of your data. Is cycle sort still useful in this case?

Comment: Not by itself, no. But maybe you could use cycle sort to get it "almost" sorted and then use another method to finish it off. The second method would be one which works well when every element is relatively close to its correct position.

Comment: It looks like someone had a similar idea in the question that was inspired by this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265525/contest-fastest-way-to-sort-a-big-array-of-gaussian-distributed-data/6269933#6269933

Answer (score 1):

Use inverse of cdf for different pdfs other than uniform distributions.

```
a = array(0, n - 1, [])          // create an empty list for each bucket
for x in input:
  a[floor(n * inverse_cdf(x))].append(x) // O(1) time for each x
input.clear()
for i in {0,...,n - 1}:
  // this sorting step costs O(|a[i]|^2) time for each bucket
  // but most buckets are small and the cost is O(1) per bucket in expectation
  insertion_sort(a[i])
  input.concatenate(a[i])
```